# How to Remove the Image URL displayed under the image while posted it to linkedin using php oauth API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, linkedin-api

Have to post only the image without displaying the image url at the bottom of image. For this, i have tried to give image url in "submitted-image-url" and the "submitted-url" as empty but its not allowing the submitted url with the empty value. So now i have changed to give only the image in "submitted-url" and omitted the parameter "submitted-image-url". By posting image with this parameter, the image is displaying with the image url link at the bottom of the image. I have to remove that url displaying with the image, is there any solution for this to remove the url link ?

Given array as :

```
$post = array(
'comment' => $_POST['txt'],
'content' => array(
'submitted-url' => $_POST['imgpath']
),
'visibility' => array(
'code' => 'anyone'
)
);
```

Comment: first thing first, did you read the linkedin api documentation?

Comment: yes i have read and this is the api array format for curl hit

Comment: lol this was 20 days ago :))